# Using getline to read a line from input file to output file

Tags: c++

Getting an error trying to compile the following bit of code:

Kind of stuck needing to use the getline function vs using extraction or insertion operators.  Not really sure what I'm doing wrong but I know it must not be proper syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    string filename;

    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    int num;

    line = "No Value";
    filename = "No Value";
    num = -1;


    inFile.open("in1.txt");
    outFile.open("out.txt");
    getline(inFile,outFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I just want it to take the line from the infile, and output it to the outfile.  But I need to use getline.

```
FileIO_2.cpp:24:24: note:   'std::ofstream {aka 
std::basic_ofstream<char>}' is not derived from 
'std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
  getline(inFile,outFile);
```

Comment: string line, filename. what are you using them for?

Comment: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ifstream&, std::ofstream&)’

Comment: you can give an input using getline(cin,line)

Answer (score 1):

#### For the error:

Change this part of code:

```
getline(inFile,outFile);
```

To this one:

```
getline(inFile, line); // get the line from "inFile" and output it to the variable "line"
outFile << line; // write "line" variable data to "outFile"
// another way is: outFile.write(line.c_str(), line.size());
```

`getline` expects an input file and output `string` variable, and not output file.
Read more about `getline` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

#### For your code:

There are unused variables, that it seems like you should use them.  `filename` probably should be use as 'input'/'output' files name, and maybe it will be even better to add another variable that will store the other file name. `int num` looks useless in this context. Your code might look better in the following form:

```
string line, input_filename, output_filename;
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

input_filename = "in1.txt";
output_filename = "out.txt";

inFile.open(input_filename);
outFile.open(output_filename);
getline(inFile, line);
outFile << line;
```

Comment: Ok, so I will need to use the insertion operator then?  There's no way around it?

Comment: For some reason, my instructor likes to leave stuff out of his assignment instructions.  I assume either to throw me off, or what have you.  From the way it was worded, it was as if I had to do this only using getline.  What you told me works though, compiled beautifully.

Comment: @Cemetery_Gates I am not familiar with any other way using getline function (and according to the source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline there is no way using getline). However, there is a way of writing without the operator, I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`getline` expects a string as it's 2nd argument, but you have given it a stream.

Read from the input file into the string, then write the string to your output file.